# Parsing information from MapQuest Reverse Geocoded Data

Tags: python, parsing, if-statement, pandas

Hi Everyone so I am having problems parsing out information from a query I made to Mapquest API. I am trying to parse out data from my geocode_data column and place into separate columns. I am trying to extract the address specifically the following components in the geocode data below.  bolded words are the things I am trying to extract.

'providedLocation': {'latLng': {'lat': 52.38330319, 'lng': 4.7959011}}, 'locations': [{'adminArea6Type': 'Neighborhood', 'street': **(4) '25 Philip Vingboonsstraat'**, 'adminArea4Type': 'County', 'adminArea3Type': 'State', '**displayLatLng': (9){'lat': 52.383324, (10){ 'lng': 4.795784}**, (7)  'adminArea3': 'Noord-Holland', 'adminArea1Type': 'Country', 'linkId': '0', 'adminArea4': 'MRA', 'dragPoint': False, 'mapUrl': 'http://www.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/v4/getmap?key=Cxk9Ng7G6M8VlrJytSZaAACnZE6pG3xp&type=map&size=225,160&pois=purple-1,52.3833236,4.7957837,0,0,|&center=52.3833236,4.7957837&zoom=15&rand=-152222465', 'type': 's', '(5)postalCode': '1067BG', 'latLng': {'lat': 52.383324, 'lng': 4.795784},(6)  'adminArea5': 'Amsterdam', 'adminArea6': 'Amsterdam', 'geocodeQuality': 'ADDRESS', 'unknownInput': '', 'adminArea5Type': 'City', 'geocodeQualityCode': 'L1AAA', (**8) 'adminArea1': 'NL'**, 'sideOfStreet': 'N'}]}

I have tried building my code but I keep getting KeyErrors. Can anyone fix my code so that I am able to extract the different address components for my study. Thanks! My code is correct until locations part towards the end. then I get an key error.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests 

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/albertgonzalobautista/Desktop/Testing11.csv')

df['geocode_data'] = ''
df['address']=''
df['st_pr_mn']= ' '

def reverseGeocode(latlng):
    result = {}
    url = 'http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/reverse?key={1}&location={0}'
    apikey = 'Cxk9Ng7G6M8VlrJytSZaAACnZE6pG3xp'
    request = url.format(latlng, apikey)
    data = json.loads(requests.get(request).text)
    if len(data['results']) > 0:
        result = data['results'][0]
    return  result


for i, row in df.iterrows():
    df['geocode_data'][i] = reverseGeocode(df['lat'][i].astype(str) + ',' + df['lon'][i].astype(str))

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if 'locations' in row['geocode_data']:
        for component in row['locations']:
            print (row['locations'])
            df['st_pr_mn'][i] = row['adminArea3']
```

Comment: What are you expecting your output to be?

Comment: so I want each component parsed out into different columns so for example the street address in one column, the display lat/lng in another and so on. in my last bit of code I am trying to create that for adminarea3 but it saying that I have key error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all , according to your `if` condition , `locations` is a key in `row['geocode_data']` , so you should try `row['geocode_data']['locations']` , not `row['locations']` , this is most probably the reason you are getting the `KeyError`.

Then according to the json you have given in the OP, seems like `locations` key stores a list, so iterate over each element (as you are doing now) and get the required element from `component` not `row`. Example -

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if 'locations' in row['geocode_data']:
        for component in row['geocode_data']['locations']:
            print (row['geocode_data']['locations'])
            df['st_pr_mn'][i] = component['adminArea3']
```

Though this would overwrite `df['st_pr_mn'][i]` with a new value for `component['adminArea3']` for every dictionary in the list of `row['geocode_data']['locations']` . If there is only one element in the list then its fine, otherwise you would have to decide how to store the multiple values , maybe use a list for that.

Comment: So how do I go about editing my code to place you changes? :)

Comment: The same place you had the `for i, row in df.iterrows(): if 'locations' in row['geocode_data']:` . Replacing your original code.

Comment: Now I am getting a Type Error string must be integers

Comment: component = row['geocode_data']['locations']
    if 'adminArea3' in component:
        df['lst_pr_mn'][i] = component['location']['adminArea3']

Comment: No, you do not need `component['location']` , just do - `component['adminArea3']` .

Comment: I am still getting the same error: Type Error                                      component = row['geocode_data']['locations']
    if 'adminArea3' in component:
        df['lst_pr_mn'][i] = component['adminArea3']

Comment: Oh ok, yes `row['geocode_data']['locations']` is a list, not a dictionary, if you just want the first element in the list, do - `component = row['geocode_data']['locations'][0]` .